# Find a matching that is stable, but neither optimal or pessimal.

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms

How can I setup a preference table to find a matching that is stable, but neither optimal or pessimal.  It can be for any number of women and men where n>2, but I'm not having any luck coming up with a preference table that when the Gale-Shapely algorithm is used on it that is stable but neither optimal or pessimal.

Answer (score 3):

Gale-Shapely always finds an extremal matching, and it doesn't seem to be easy to modify it to find something else.

One way to construct a set of preferences and a non-extremal stable matching by hand is to place $n$ men and $n$ women in a circle with men and women alternating. Everyone regardless of their gender prefers a partner that has the shortest *clockwise* distance from themself.

Then for every $k\ge 1$, the matching that pairs each man with the woman $2k-1$ positions clockwise from him will be stable. $k=1$ produces the male-optimal matching; $k=n$ produces the female-optimal one.